# Chromedriver bug on linux server

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I want to deploy my Java Spring app which uses Selenium and ChromeDriver to a Linux server.
I have everything installed with the proper version like this:

```
root@skarpe:~/backend# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912})
root@skarpe:~/backend# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 113.0.5672.63
```

Also this part of the code doesn't work:

```java
public static WebDriver initWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setCapability("followRedirects", true);
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
        options.addArguments("--disable-javascript");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("--disable-discovery");
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=CSSAnimations");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

This is the code where I call the method:

```java
try{
       webDriver = ScraperUtility.initWebDriver();
       LOGGER.info("Scraper init finished");
}catch (Exception e){
       LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
}
```

And this is the log I receive:

```
WARN 1 --- [pool-2-thread-4] com.scraper.api.scraper.WebshopScraper   : The driver executable must exist: /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Although when I run ChromeDriver from the location it works:

```
root@skarpe:~/backend# /usr/bin/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912})
```

I run this in a docker container, and I also tried to use the selenium standalone where this is the only error I receive:

```
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.1.4', revision: '535d840ee2'
System info: host: '90441c5fe4b4', ip: '172.23.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-71-generic', java.version: '17.0.2'
```

Comment: Did you try passing the path to chromedriver directly at `webDriver = ScraperUtility.initWebDriver();` ?